# Faker avatar is not working in my project

Tags: reactjs, firebase, faker.js

I'm using faker for random information but avtar is unable to open and showing error by clinking this link https://cdn.fakercloud.com/avatars/victor_haydin_128.jpg
and i had updated all to latest version.
Please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

The fakercloud.com domain [has expired](https://www.whois.com/whois/fakercloud.com), and the author appears to have wiped out [the whole project](https://web.archive.org/web/20220105080028/https://github.com/Marak/faker.js) for political reasons.

Based on the unreliability, I'm transitioning away from faker at this point, but if you want to continue using it, you could fork a previous version of the code and change the hard-coded link from fakercloud.com to something that works (either something you control or another similar service).